# Best service to get Company Info?

Tags: api, service, public

I need some **PUBLIC** sevice, similar service like LInkedin API for companies where you can get company info in xml version.
The service has to provide Company name,email domain,description,location ...etc

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

Google Places? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceDetailsResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <name>Google Sydney</name>
  <vicinity>5/48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont</vicinity>
  <type>store</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <formatted_phone_number>(02) 9374 4000</formatted_phone_number>
  <formatted_address>5/48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont NSW, Australia</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   ...
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>-33.8669710</lat>
    <lng>151.1958750</lng>
   </location>
  </geometry>
  <rating>4.6</rating>
  <url>http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10281119596374313554</url>
  <icon>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png</icon>
  <reference>CnRlAAAAmEVjMMmgnwJelvu3C6FBY7IbBnTFo79cG4wFECOAZBspmGrr5XLU8PUlbfP6pyBSEFtq7qHJcauhj-VbBvd-p-CK9R5PdKr17WI0cqJ91gIXVgMIpMl8UviFq_xSzxdE_g7dL1QwsvC9_jriAVkbxBIQRIYHAi7IRd8oePOmHImOWRoUmObrEH8JZRUVv6CRSsJz9OA20wo</reference>
  <id>4f89212bf76dde31f092cfc14d7506555d85b5c7</id>
  <international_phone_number>+61 2 9374 4000</international_phone_number>
  <website>http://www.google.com.au/</website>
 </result>
</PlaceDetailsResponse>
```

Comment: Nice one,but this is experimental .. i need something that its already tested and relevant